# How many human cells will get affected at the prick of a pin?

Tags: mass

Wikipedia states that there are 10^14 cells in a human body. My question is if I was to take a needle or a pin and pierce it just 2 mm in the body, how many cells will I be piercing?

Comment: Not really a physics question.

Comment: it is a biology question

Comment: Indeed I also do not believe there is much physics here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about biology not physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physics has a concept of the mean free path (MFP). We can use the same principles to tackle this question.

Even in the case of an infinitesimally thin pin that goes 2 mm into the body we can still calculate "roughly" how many cells are traversed.

First we estimate the mean volume of a cell: 80 kg of water, $10^{14}$ cells, so one cell has a mass of $8\cdot 10^{-13}$ kg ; with a density of 1000 kg/m<sup>3</sup> it has a volume of $8\cdot 10^{-16} m^3$ and a linear dimension of (roughly) 10 µm.

If these were neatly stacked as cubes, you would traverse 200 per mm, so **in 2 mm you might damage 400 cells**.

That is the answer for an infinitely thin needle. I didn't bother with corrections for cell shape and stacking... the additional assumptions needed would not improve the accuracy of this answer.

In reality, your pin has a finite diameter and this means it will affect far more cells - you can think of it as being a drill that takes out a cylindrical volume. Again, this is in close parallel with the MFP calculations from kinetics.

If the pin has a diameter of 0.5 mm, then at a depth of 2 mm it has a volume of $1.6\cdot10^{-7} m^3$ and therefore affects about **200 million cells**.

As you can see - there are many orders of magnitude difference in the answer depending on tiny changes in assumptions.

Comment: I'm most impressed with your answer. Where others simply regarded it as a biology question just because I mentioned human cells, you went to the core of the problem and provided exactly the answer I was looking for. Brilliant answer.

Comment: a cosmic muon traversing the human body is like an infinitely thin needle for the order of magnitude of the cell.

Comment: Do cosmic muons pierce cells? What do we define as "piercing"? Does piercing involve creating a puncture?